# Python neo4j - Can we display the graph instance?

Tags: python, neo4j, graph-visualization

I'm trying python `neo4j` library.
One of the result it can return is [graph instance](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/current/types/graph.html), **I'm wondering whether we can visualize this graph in python?**

Here's an example of the whole code:

```
from neo4j import GraphDatabase

driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost:7687", auth=(username, pwd))

def delete_all(tx):
    result = tx.run("""match (n) detach delete n""").single()
    if result is None:
        print('Removed All!')

def create_entity(tx, entity_id, entity_name, entity_properties):
    query = """CREATE ("""+entity_id+""": """+entity_name+entity_properties+""")"""
    result = tx.run(query)

def display_all(tx, query):
    results = tx.run(query)
    for record in results:
        print(record)
    return results.graph()

with driver.session() as session:
    session.write_transaction(delete_all)
    session.write_transaction(create_entity, entity_id='Alice', entity_name='Client',
    entity_properties = "{name:'Alice', ip: '1.1.1.1', shipping_address: 'a place', billing_address: 'a place'}")

    graph = session.read_transaction(display_all, query="MATCH (c:Client) RETURN c")
```

If we print out the returned `graph`, it looks like this:
[image: python neo4j graph]

**So, is there anyway in python to display this graph?**